# Android PlaceAutocomplete activity result list text overlapping each other

Tags: android, autocomplete, google-play-services

I'm using PlaceAutocomplete activity as described here: http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.co.id/2015/12/autocomplete-widget-and-updated-place.html.

I have problem with it since I update the gradle library to version 9.x.x. I'm currently using v9.4.0:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3.4'
```

when I search some place, the result is like this:

[image: result list text overlapping each other]

I think the problem is in the library. Any help will be appreciated :)

**UPDATE**

This bug was handled by Google in issue

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35829225

The fix was implemented in Google Play Services 9.6 (21 Sep 2016)

Comment: Have you put some changes to example's code? If yes could you please provide it.

Comment: @anivaler : I only change the version in gradle file. nothing else :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue earlier. And its said that it will be fixed in next release. So kindly use the latest and check if it still exist. Or else you need to do custom autocomplete using Google Places API as I done to solve that issue.

Comment: thanks for your idea. I'll wait for updates from google and if I have time, I will make custom autocomplete as you said

Comment: @nivedh Where did you get the info about this being fixed in the next release? Have you seen it in a public tracker? If so, kindly provide a link.

Comment: Bug report filed. Please star: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10292