# Android Google PlacePicker showing overlapping text

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-places-api

I am using google `play-services version 9.4.0` and i am using [PlaceAutocomplete with overlay mode](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete#option_2_use_an_intent_to_launch_the_autocomplete_activity). but now it has this weird overlap issue.

[image: this happens when i try to search a location]

Thanks.

Comment: Can confirm. I'm having the same issue. Seems to be an issue if you type too fast and the search results change. play services 9.0.2

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38733743/android-placeautocomplete-activity-result-list-text-overlapping-each-other

Comment: @Stuartsoft thats what i thought, and i updated it to latest 9.4.0 from 9.0+ 
but its still there

Comment: Bug report filed: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10292

Comment: I am facing overlapping issue while using 9.2.0.
Can you please let us know in which version issue resolved?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Ravi its still there even in `9.4.0`. you can either  roll back to `8.+` version or wait if it is fixed in the next version.

Comment: @TaimurAmjad Thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

Resolved in Google Play Services 9.6
https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10292