# Android PlaceAutocomplete search result mixup

Tags: android, autocomplete, google-play-services

I followed the [google play documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlguDl.png) for implementing autocomplete using "Use an intent to launch the autocomplete activity."

But sometimes the results are showing all mixed up and overlapped.

Below is the code that i am using :

```
try {
    // The autocomplete activity requires Google Play Services to be available. The intent
    // builder checks this and throws an exception if it is not the case.
    AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
            .setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_CITIES)
            .build();
    Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN).setFilter(typeFilter)
            .build(MainActivity.this);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 111);
} catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
    // Indicates that Google Play Services is either not installed or not up to date. Prompt
    // the user to correct the issue.
    GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(MainActivity.this, e.getConnectionStatusCode(),
            0 /* requestCode */).show();
} catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
    // Indicates that Google Play Services is not available and the problem is not easily
    // resolvable.
    String message = "Google Play Services is not available: " +
            GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorString(e.errorCode);

    Log.e("", message);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

[image: Screen shot]

Is this a  Google Play service SDK problem or code problem?

Comment: Post your design code and manifest code of this activity.

Comment: I don’t think  design require cause its google places libraries own layout and its native code provided by google

Comment: check this similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/38738286/6316670